# How to assert min. time between observable emits

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have an RxJS observable that emits values after random times between 0 and 1000ms.

How do I assert that there is a gap of at least 200ms between each emit of the observable? No values should be dropped / skipped and values should still be emitted in the order they come in.

Comment: _"at no least 200ms"_ - could you please clarify this? Do you mean to say the successive emssions should atleast be 200ms apart from each other? In other words, an emission needs to be buffered if the last emission was within 200ms?

Comment: It seems you want to assert something that is not true, is true. If your observable emits values at random times between 0 and 1000ms, there may be times when the period between two emitted values is less than 200 ms (one emit at 0ms, one emit at 10ms, for example).

Comment: It was a typo. Should read "there is a gap of at least 200ms"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could achieve that by combining your source observable with interval operator, using the zip operator.

zip documentation from rxjs:

> Combines multiple Observables to create an Observable whose values are
> calculated from the values, in order, of each of its input
> Observables.